# Hibernate/MySQL cascade error on delete parent

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a java web project that uses:

- Spring `4.3.2`
- **Hibernate** `5.2.2`/JPA `2.0`+ `MySQL5InnoDBDialect`
- **MySQL** `5.6.15`-`innoDB` (on EasyPHP/PHPMyAdmin) + **JDBC** `connector 6.0.4`

I'm facing a error when i want to delete some data. But, this problem does exist only if i want to **Delete** a parent row that **have children** and one of his **children also** **have** at least one **child**.

---

**Goal:** I want the action/query to delete the selected row and its children and grandchildren.

---

**Error code:** in server output

> 28-Sep-2016 11:51:30.345 ERROR [http-nio-80-exec-42] org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement

**Parent classe:** `Pavillon`

```
//...
private Set<Table> pavTables;
//...
@JsonIgnore
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "pavillon", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<com.optimal.waiter.component.model.Table> getPavTables() {
    return pavTables;
}
//...setters & others
```

**Child classe:** `Table`

```
//...
private Pavillon pavillon;
//...
@NotNull
@Basic(optional = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "PAV_ID")
public Pavillon getPavillon() {
    return pavillon;
}
@JsonIgnore
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "table", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Reservation> getTableReservations() {
    return tableReservations;
}
//...setters & others
```

**Grandchild class:** `Reservation`

```
//...
private Table table;
//...
@NotNull
@Basic(optional = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "TAB_ID", nullable = false)
public Table getTable() {
    return table;
}
//...setters & others
```

**SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE PAVILLONS
(
   PAV_ID               INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PAV_NOM              VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
   PAV_DES              TEXT,
   PAV_TYPE             INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   PRIMARY KEY (PAV_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE TABLES
(
   TAB_ID               INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PAV_ID               INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
   TAB_DISPO            TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
   TAB_TYPE             INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   PRIMARY KEY (TAB_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE RESERVATIONS
(
   RES_ID               INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   TAB_ID               INT(10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (RES_ID)
);
ALTER TABLE TABLES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PAV_TAB FOREIGN KEY (PAV_ID)
      REFERENCES PAVILLONS (PAV_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE RESERVATIONS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TABLE_RESERVATION FOREIGN KEY (TAB_ID)
  REFERENCES TABLES (TAB_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

**PS:** the error still even when i try to delete then using SQL query directly in `PHPMyAdmin`.

**Error code:** in server output

> ERROR 1451: 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`commandes`, CONSTRAINT `FK_TAB_COMM`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`TAB_ID`) REFERENCES `tables` (`TAB_ID`)) SQL Statement:
>   DELETE FROM `pavillons` WHERE `PAV_ID`='2'

That's why i **think** the **problem is in DB side**.

Waiting for your help, any suggestion will help.

Comment: please update your question showing the output of `show create table myTable` where myTable are at least the ones for the children

Comment: I believe you are mixing Hibernate and JPA annotations. I am not sure if this works. Can you try removing Hibernate's `Cascade` annotation and use `@OneToMany` as `@OneToMany(..., cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` - and do note that `CascadeType` here is `javax.persistence.CascadeType`!

Comment: The foreign key name in the error message is different from the one you used. Is it possible you have multiple FKs defined and one of them does not have the on delete cascade part?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos i tried it both ways and there's no difference.in addition, if i use `javax.persistence.CascadeType` there was more unwanted things to set in the `DAO`. No need for this and it is not the problem in this case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Shadow it could be!!, I have another class named `Commande` attached with the class Table using `@OneToOne` relation. it mean conceptually that a Table can have many reservations and a command is setter to one table and the table ID is required on it.
I think this is the problem thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the comment of @Shadow i I figured that another table/entity related to the grandchild cause this problem.

**Any one face this problem** in the future, **should recheck all relations of each related table.**

eg: `Table`**A** ---> `Table`**B** ---> `Table`**C** ---> `Table`**D**

To delete a row of `Table`**A** (the way i wanted to do - Cascade way), it need to have all the way relations to `Table`**D** correctly cascaded `ON DELETE CASCADE`. specially if all `FK` are forced `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior - **to not generate orphaned rows**. So it is not exactly a problem with the database but a feature of `InnoDB` engine.

Try to familiarize with `InnoDB`s [Foreign Key Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point of view. do you think the data in my DB contains some orphan rows before the delete process?

Comment: @MalekBoubakri no, but there would be, if your query would succeed. Thats why it fails.

Comment: My fault,!! I do edit my question, please check it again. i forgot to mention my goal.